# Datatables PHP MYSQL - How to display specific entries

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have a database with the following columns:
(`okladka`, `imie`, `nazwisko`, `tytul`, `rodzaj`, `info`, `download`, `data`)

My DB name: serwer144221_SwiatBook
Table name: bazaplikow

In the value "rodzaj" each entry contains one word: "audiobook" or "ebook"
I would like to display in the table only those entries where the word in "ebook" appears.

How to read all rows from a database table where the column "rodzaj" contains a value "ebook"

This is my Source Code Datatables:

```
 <?php  
        $servername = "xyz";
        $username = "xyz";
        $password = "xyz";
        $database = "serwer144221_SwiatBook";

        // Create connection
        $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

        // Check connection
        if ($connection->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
        }

        // read all row from database table
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT rodzaj * FROM bazaplikow";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            die("Invalid query: " . $connection->error);
        }
```

?>

```
<section class="section-1">
    <h3 align="center">Baza plików</h3>  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table id="bazaplikow_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%";>  
                      <thead>  
                           <tr>  
                                <td align="center">Okładka</td>  
                                <td align="center">Imię</td>  
                                <td align="center">Nazwisko</td>  
                                <td align="center">Tytuł</td>  
                                <td align="center">Rodzaj</td>  
                                <td align="center">Info</td>  
                                <td align="center">Download</td> 
                                <td align="center">Data</td> 
                           </tr>  
                      </thead>  
                      <?php  
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  
                           echo '  
                           <tr>  
                                <td align="center"><img src="'.$row["okladka"].'"  width="98" height="128"></td>  
                                <td align="center">'.$row["imie"].'</td>  
                                <td align="center">'.$row["nazwisko"].'</td>  
                                <td align="center">'.$row["tytul"].'</td>  
                                <td align="center">'.$row["rodzaj"].'</td>  
                                <td align="center"><a href="'.$row["info"].'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>  
                                <td align="center"><a href="'.$row["download"].'"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>   
                                <td align="center">'.$row["data"].'</td>               
                           </tr>  
                           ';  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
    </section>


        <script>  
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bazaplikow_data').DataTable({
        order: [[7, 'desc']],
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: This looks like a question about how to write a SQL `WHERE` clause. This is not valid SQL: `SELECT DISTINCT rodzaj * FROM bazaplikow`. I am guessing you want something like this instead: `select okladka, imie, nazwisko, tytul, rodzaj, info, download, data from bazaplikow where rodzaj = 'ebook'` - or maybe `where rodzaj like '%ebook%'` - and maybe you don't need all columns.

Comment: But it would be easier to help you and to avoid guesswork if you can share what happens with your current code. Does it throw any errors? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong it should be

```
 SELECT * from bazaplikow where rodzaj = 'ebook';
```